# Vsim not found in Quartus

Tags: 14.04

I need help, I installed Quartus (only extract the tar, and execute the run files) in my home folder, but when I try to excecute a Test.vwf  from a proyect, it shows me

```
**** Running the ModelSim simulation **** 
/home/renejesus/altera/14.1/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim -c -do proyect1.do
/home/renejesusgv/altera/14.1/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim: 322: exec: /home/renejesusgv/altera/14.1/modelsim_ase/bin/../linux/vsim: not found
Error.
```

I've not assigned variables.
I'm using Ubuntu 14_04 64 bits
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did you get this working? I own the CD set, Vsim is on a separate disk

Comment: Have you changed the installed path or moved it after installation? I notice from your output `/home/renejesus/` & `/home/renejesusgv/` !

Comment: I did not change the installed path, that was my default.

Comment: @ReNeeJesus, Could you try last quartus release 16? There is also a quick trick that I expect it to work, If your username is `renejesus` create a symlink using `ln -s /home/renejesus /home/renejesusgv`. I have just installed 16.1 release few days ago to `/opt` and it is working fin following this post http://www.fpga-dev.com/altera-usb-blaster-with-ubuntu/